# Using ngFor add two elements to a row then create a new row

Tags: angular, ngfor

so I have been trying for a while now to iterate over an array of objects using *ngFor, with two elements being placed inside of a row.
After each 2 componenets have been added to a row a new row should be generated and so on.

What I have tried so far below:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let prod of products; let i = index; let even = even">
<span *ngIf="even">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
        <div>
            <img src="{{ prod.imagePath }}" alt="{{ prod.name }}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 150px; max-width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>{{ prod.name }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Price: {{ prod.price }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
        <div>
            <img src="{{ products[i+1].imagePath }}" alt="{{ products[i+1].name }}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 150px; max-width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>{{ products[i+1].name }}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Price: {{ products[i+1].price }}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</span>
```

I have checked all the relevant questions I could find here but none seemed to fix my issue.

At the minute, each element goes into it's own row, regardless of what I do.

I have tried to change the sizes of the containers for each of the elements but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why not just put the `ngIf` on the inner div with the `col` class? ps a `DIV` tag isn't valid inside a `SPAN` tag.

Comment: @DaleBurrell. thanks for the response, I did not know that div's weren't valid inside of a span, good to know! I have changed the span to a <ng-template> anyway while I was waiting, which has solved 50% of the problem. Now I just need to try and get them centered somehow. Thanks!

Comment: you can also build a new products array that will have two elements combined at every index: Ex: `let products = [[{product1}{product2}], [{product3},{product4}]]` and loop over them for printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is by transforming the structure of your products array so that it is an array of arrays. Then the structure you want is easy to loop over and print.

You can do the transformation using a `pipe`.
Ex:

```
     @Pipe({
       name: 'updateRows'
     })
     export class UpdateRowsPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform<T>(value: T[], perRow: number): T[][] {
          let rows: T[][] = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i += perRow) {
            rows.push(value.slice(i, i + perRow))
        }
        return rows;
    }

  }
```

and then use it where you have `*ngFor`:

```
    <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of products | updateRows:2">
        <div *ngFor="let product of row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-3">
                 <div>
                <img src="{{ product.imagePath }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 150px; max-width: 150px;">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>Price: {{ product.price }}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
          <!-- Do some more fun things here --> 
     </div>   

</div>
```